# Unexpected error when ActiveWorksheet not source worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet with column headers (in row 1) and under each header an array of between 1 and 255 values. I have code that creates a new sheet for each heading and paste the values (starting from row 2 to row n, different for each header) and renames the sheet to the heading title. Assume that the heading titles are valid sheet names.

The code below works fine when my `ActiveSheet` is the `Data` worksheet.

However, when I run the code with a different `ActiveSheet` (within the same workbook) I get this error:

`Run-time error 1004:
Method Range’ of object ‘_Worksheet failed`

The debugger tells me that the error occurs on the line `Set src = ws.Range(Cells(2, i), Cells(lastRow, i))`. Why is this error occurring?

```
Sub MakeNewWorksheets()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim target As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    Dim s As String

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Data")

    For i = 1 To ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count
        s = ws.Cells(1, i)
        If Not SheetExists(s, wb) Then
            Set target = wb.Sheets.Add(, wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count))
            target.Name = s
        Else
            Set target = wb.Worksheets(s)
        End If

        ' Find data from front sheet
        Dim src As Range
        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row

        Set src = ws.Range(Cells(2, i), Cells(lastRow, i))
        'Debug.Print src.Address

        ' Set values in target sheet
        target.Range("A1:A256").Value = src.Value
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is occuring because the `Cells(2,1)` and the `Cells(lastRow, i)` are not specifically linked to a sheet in your code and thus linked to the ActiveSheet.  The command you give should create a range on sheet `ws` with cells on sheet `ActiveSheet`.  This is not possible.

Change it into (add `ws.` in front of the `Cells(..)`:

```
Set src = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, i), ws.Cells(lastRow, i))
```